# How to remove an elevation of the ion-toolbar?

Tags: css, ionic2

In the following code, I want to remove the ion-toolbar. Look at this:

### Code

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar >
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title></ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

### Image

[image]

How to remove an elevation of the `ion-toolbar`?

Comment: you mean not seeing the whole toolbar? what triggers hiding that?

Comment: Could you be a little more specific about what elevation?

Comment: I'm talking about the shadow of the toolbar.

Comment: @AckLay There should be a `box-shadow` property in css of the `ion-toolbar` somewhere. Could you check if you can find it? Let me know if it works.

Comment: @SagarKulkarni I solved. See this: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/183219/35406

Comment: @AckLay Cool. Add it to the answer and accept it then. :) Also, remember to check the CSS properties next time. This can also be solved by `box-shadow`. no-border class just gives that property I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with this response from SOpt:

```
<Ion-header no-border>
...
<Ion-header>
```

More details [in documentations](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/toolbar/Toolbar/#usage).

Answer (score 0):

You can use it's default class `ion-no-border`.

```js
<br>
eg.
<ion-header [translucent]="true" class="ion-no-border"></ion-header>
```